# How to test a Sails.js app using Jest instead of Mocha?

Tags: sails.js, jestjs

The [documentation for Sails 0.12.11](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing) explains how to set up testing using the Mocha framework. I would like to use Jest to do that.

I tried using the same code for `bootstrap.test.js`, but replacing `before` with `beforeAll` and `after` with `afterAll`; replacing `this.timeout(5000)` with `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 5000`. Because Jest expects at least one test in a file, I made a dummy test there to make sure it did not complain.

Then, in another file (`some.test.js`), I tried to reference a dummy service that I created just to see if things work. With Mocha, any Sails service should be available by default, without any require statement.

```
it('should call the dummy service fine', () => {
  expect(DummyService.doSomething()).toBe('ok');
});
```

Upon running the tests with `jest tests/*`, I come across the following log:

[image: Sails console.error using Jest]

Furthermore, the dummy service test fails because it says it is not defined.

```
 FAIL  tests/some.test.js
  ● should call the dummy service fine

    ReferenceError: DummyService is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

Jest does seem to be well suited to tests sails.

Jest philosophy is to have many tests running concurrently with independent state this means jest has no way to use global setup file.

Using jest for sails would mean :

- Starting an instance of sails per test which could be memory hungry if you've got many test.
- Customize its orm (waterline) so that it uses a random file for the database for each test instance to accomplish clean state.

Now you may argue that sails does it wrong and could be made from the startup to support the kind of testing jest promote.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is still relevant.

I won't lie you. It was not easy :(. It took me all the day but after all I was able to configure

1. **Eslint**
2. **Prettier**
3. **Jest**

check how it all works in my [repo](https://github.com/tugorez/sails-jest) and feel free to contact me if you have any doubt.

https://github.com/tugorez/sails-jest

Comment: Interesting approach. Just curious: using `"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"`, wouldn't Sails lift as many times as there are test files? That was my problem. If I have 10 test files, it would lift Sails 10 times, something not really desired...

Comment: Hi @nbkhope. Accordingly to the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#beforeallfn), the answer is no. It runs just once before all tests. Did you have any related problem?

Comment: That is wrong, according tot the official doc "The path to a module that runs some code to configure or set up the testing framework **before each test**.". [Source](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string)

Comment: Edouard you're right. The server is lifted and lowered between each test. My apologizes for the confusion.

Comment: I've added an answer which I think is more appropriate for the question.